# Null pointer Exception when using static as object?

Tags: java, exception, object, pointers, static

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class sample
{  
public void print_func() 
{
System.out.println("This is fromprint_fun");
} 
}

class test
{
public final static sample s = null; 
}

public class hello
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
test.s.print_func();
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at hello.main(hello.java:22)

Can anybody let me know what actually the problem is ?

Comment: Your question would be much better if you followed Java naming conventions for all your names, and indented your code sensibly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - `s` is null. You never initialize it to a non-null reference, so when you try to dereference it by calling `s.print_func`, that throws the exception.

This has nothing to do with the variable being static. You'll get the exact same exception if you do this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    sample s = null;
    s.print_func();
}
```

EDIT: To address your comment more fully, look at this:

```
class test
{
    public final static sample s = null; 
}
```

This declares a class, and within it declares a *variable*. That's *not* an object. It's important to distinguish between three concepts:

- A variable, which is a named storage location. A variable has a value, and in this case it's a value which is a reference
- A reference, which is always either null or a way of getting to an object of a compatible type
- An object

So if you had:

```
public static final sample s = new sample();
```

Then `s` would still be a variable; its value would be a non-null reference, which referred to an object of type `sample`.

Think of `s` as being like a piece of paper, which can either be blank (a `null` reference) 
 or contain the street address of a house. The address itself isn't the house - it's just a way of *getting* to the house. There can be several pieces of paper all with the same address written on them. Copying the address to another piece of paper doesn't create a new house.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @HelloWorld: you haven't created an object, and indeed there's no such thing as a static object. You've declared a variable, and that's not the same thing. If you initialize that variable to a non-null value, the problem will go away.

Comment: @HelloWorld: I've edited my answer to give some more details.

Comment: Hi Jon,  What you have explained it correct. But my intention is call the print_fun  using the static object that i have created in class test .So how would I do it ?

Comment: Ok. then how actually System.outln.println() works without any creation of object of printstream  class. I see that its just the static object 'out' calling the funtion println() without creating the actual object of printstream class in System class.

Comment: In the java.lang.System class we cannot find any new printstream() .It only has the static reference variable printstream out.But even 'out' is able to call println() function in printstream class. How did that Work ????????????/

Comment: @HelloWorld: How are you looking at the `java.lang.System` implementation? `System.out` is a non-null reference - even if the `System` class doesn't create that instance directly. Even though `System.out`, it's set by `System.setOut` via native code - it behaves a bit oddly, basically. I strongly suspect the initial value is populated by native code as well. It's not a good model for you to learn about how Java works.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Till now I was in the assumption that 'out' as simply a reference for printstream without any object worked fine.So I have tried to replicate the same in my sample program to work it out.But is seems that native code is used to initialize the out reference variable. Thanks a lot Jon for your help . If possible fro you can you please try to ellaborate how 'out' refernce variable actually works and where exactly that printstream class object is created via native code ?

Comment: @HelloWorld: No, because I'd have to go digging into the guts of the JRE, without any actual benefit. It's *incredibly* unlikely that you'll actually ever need to do anything similar, so in this particular case it's probably okay to just think of `System.out` as "special".